# ViewPager item without selecting an item from the indicator

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

Is it possible to create a `ViewPager` with the following scenario?
I want to have a `ViewPager` with 5 fragments. These 5 fragments are bound to a `ViewPagerIndicator`. (already got this)
Now I want to create an extra fragment at the start before all other fragments and that the `ViewPagerIndicator` is not selecting anything when this fragment is the current item.
Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Please add your code. Also, could you elaborate?

Comment: 'not selecting anything when this fragment is the current item' what do u mean by this ?